# Anyone knows something about EntityFramework.MappingAPI development progress?

Tags: entity-framework, codeplex

Does anyone know something about the [EntityFramework.MappingAPI](https://efmappingapi.codeplex.com/)
development progress?

The last update has been in March 2014 and the developer last visited the site in 2015.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you not to use this tool for many reasons. If you need to retrieve the database/schema information, then just use MetadataWorkspace.

Comment: Do you maybe have some examples in mind, what could cause problems? Thanks

Comment: For a just simple reason it was tested with EF 4.1. between 4.1 and 6.1 a lot of features are interdouced and changed. if you have a newer version than 4.1 then you should thinking before use it.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comming accross from somewhere looking for the same thing, i found this project, which is a fork of the MappingApi and is still under maintaince.
The developer also responded on a question of mine, so i think that this could be an alternativ to the MappingApi, if your not using EF5 or older anymore

http://schneids.net/get-table-info-for-your-entities-in-entity-framework/

Comment: Author here.  I maintain this library and use it in a production capacity every day.  Please feel free to ask questions or file issues if you have any problems!